# How can I rewrite this code using a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

The following is a code I have written to change a grid color to indigo upon clicking it, then removing the color upon the second click. However, I do not know how to rewrite the if-else statement using a ternary operator.

```
const grid1=document.querySelector(".cell01")
grid1.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    console.log(e);
    if (grid1.style.backgroundColor) {
      grid1.style.backgroundColor = "";
      } else {
        grid1.style.backgroundColor = "indigo";
      }
})
```

Thank you for your help in advance (:

**Update**
Thanks for the answers! But now I have one more inquiry -- I wanted to try different ways of rewriting the same code, and came up with this:
`grid1.style.backgroundColor=(grid1.style.backgroundColor!=true) ? "indigo" : "";`

It did exactly what I wanted with the expression `(grid1.style.backgroundColor==false)`, but not in the case of the former. Is there a reason why?

Comment: @MattMorgan That is a php dupe, this is JS.

Comment: Thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward translation into a ternary:

```js
grid1.style.backgroundColor = grid1.style.backgroundColor ? "" : "indigo";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grid1.style.backgroundColor = grid1.style.backgroundColor ? '' : 'indigo'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
grid1.style.backgroundColor = grid1.style.backgroundColor ? "" : "indigo";
```

Checkout below reference to learn more about ternary operator
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ternary-operator-javascript-if-statement-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You could asssign with taking a property from an object.

```
backgroundColor = { indigo: '', '': 'indigo' }[backgroundColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a ternary operator, you can simply the change the code as per your control names.

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const curColour = document.body.style.backgroundColor;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = curColour === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```